# How to convert a java object to a json object and send to asmx web service as a paramenter in android?

Tags: android, json, web-services, asmx, gson

I am calling a web method in asmx web service from my android app and that Method accepts a json object.  When I debug my app it gives me following exception "Cannot Serialize 1001.10"( its my one of class variables value ). here below I am sending data by hard coding values( for test purposes)

```
            Item itm=new Item();
        ItemType itype=new ItemType();

    itm.Description="Good Product";
    itm.BarcodeNumber="1234";
    itm.Depreciation=(float) 100.56;
    itm.AgencyId=1;
    itm.ItemCode="Android";
    itm.ItemValue=(float) 9999.99;
    itm.PurDate=new Date(0);   //Date I am sending here...
    itm.PurValue=(float) 1001.10;

    itype.Itemname="Android App";
    itype.Make="Android Developers";
    itype.Model="2013 Model";
    itype.Year=new Date(0);

    itm.iType=itype;
```

I am getting exception as "Cannont serialize 1001.01" after  itm.PurValue (caught exception when I debug my app)

I thought it is due to date format but since my Web service accepts json object I thought the error could be format of object I am sending.

To convert a java object to json object I have added the gson.jar file into my java build path - -libraries .

and use Gson to convert java object to json string and passed that json string to web service.

When I run the app it aborts and says " Unfortunately, My App stopped working"

Here is my code which I use for converting java object to json string.

```
            Gson gson = new Gson();  //Exception Occurred at this point when control comes here it is giving as Invocation Target Exception 
    String json=gson.toJson(itm);

        p.setName("ThisItem");
    p.setValue(json);
    p.setType(String.class);
    request.addProperty(p);
```

and the remaining code is common... but for reference I am pasting that code too here.

```
           SoapSerializationEnvelope envelope=new SoapSerializationEnvelope(SoapEnvelope.VER12);
        envelope.dotNet=true;
        envelope.setOutputSoapObject(request);
        HttpTransportSE androidTSE=new HttpTransportSE(URL);

        try
        {
            androidTSE.call(Soap_Action, envelope);
            SoapObject response=(SoapObject) envelope.getResponse();
            return response.toString();
        }
        catch(Exception ex)
        {
            return ex.toString();
        }
```

I am getting an exception as Invocation Target Exception when I debug my app with above gson code inculded.

what may be the problem? Is the date format I am using in my object or the format of converting java object to gson object?

Finally I like to say that I want to send an json object to my asmx web service. How can I solve this problem. Please any one could share any ideas. I am struggling for this error for 7 hours.

Thanks in advance
Ganesh

Answer (score 0):

I know I am too late but for others looking for similar answers :

I had this error when i was trying to send a character to my soap service.The problem is with this piece of code :

```
p.setName("ThisItem");
p.setValue(json);
p.setType(String.class);
request.addProperty(p);
```

What you would need to do to solve it is :

```
request.addAttribute("This Item",json);
```

Yes, that worked !